# jQuery not hiding labels and elements

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm tying to use using jQuery in Woocommerce to hide form fields in my billing field based on a select box value, the jQuery does hide the element nor the labels:
My code for this is:

````
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code in here
  jQuery(document).on('input','billing_condition', function() {
 
      mySecFunc();
})
function mySecFunc() {
    // your function code
if(jQuery('#billing_condition').val() == 'house'){
    console.log('before');
    
    jQuery('#billing_complex_name').hide();
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_name"]').hide();
    
    jQuery('#billing_complex_address').hide();
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_address"]').hide();
    
    jQuery('#billing_complex_address_inside').hide();
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_address_inside]').hide();

    console.log('after');
    
}else{
    console.log('before');
    
    jQuery('label[for="billing_address_1"]').hide();
    jQuery('#billing_address_1').hide();
    
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_name"]').show();
    jQuery('#billing_complex_complex_name').show();
    jQuery('#billing_complex_address').show();
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_address"]').show();
    
    jQuery('#billing_complex_address_inside').show();
    jQuery('label[for="billing_complex_address_inside"]').show();

    console.log('after');
    
}
}})```

The elements were going prior however are not at current nor are the labels.
````

Comment: I think you should remove the `#` in `jQuery('label[for="#billing_complex_name"]').hide();` but please include you html to be use

Comment: ^^ what @CarstenLøvboAndersen said. Remember that the `#` is not part of the ID, it's what tells CSS you're using an ID selector. The ID is just what follows it. The `for` attribute contains the ID, not a CSS ID selector.

Comment: Side note: If you put the input *inside* the label, you don't need to set up their relationship via IDs, which is simpler to maintain (and would mean you only have to hide the label). That's not always possible, but with flex and grid, it's often possible.

Comment: As above, put another way: `$("[for=" + id + "]")` vs `$("#" + id)` - for= uses an id, not a selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably try `keyup` event on your input, I have managed to solve your issue by that.
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/iftikharyk/ktsLw9vp/)

> HTML

```
<label for="#billing_condition">Label</label>
<input type="text" id="billing_condition"/>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $("#billing_condition");
  input.keyup(function() {
    if (input.val() == "abc") {
      $('label[for="#billing_condition"]').hide();
    } else {
        $('label[for="#billing_condition"]').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my full code please ?

Comment: As I said, try keyup first then tell if the issue persists.